# Cloudwatch Metric showing wrong value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an application publishing a custom cloudwatch metric using boto's put_metric_data. The metric shows the number of tasks waiting in a redis queue.

The 1-minute max shows '3', 1-minute min shows '0' and 1-minute average shows '1.5'.

It seems that the application is correctly setting the value to zero, but some other process is overwriting it with 3 at the same time, but I can't find this to stop it.

Is it possible to see logs for PutMetricData to diagnose where this value might be coming from?

Comment: If your application stops sending the data, does CloudWatch still report any metrics? Try that first to confirm that it isn't your application that is sending the unwanted data.

Comment: Yes, if I shut down my application the 1 minute average increases to 3 from 1.5, so there is maybe some other instance with the process running sending a PutMetricData value of 3.

Comment: Worst case, you could create a new Custom Metric and point your app to that, ignoring the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, **Amazon CloudTrail** would be the ideal way to discover information about API calls being made to your AWS account. Unfortunately, `PutMetricData` is **not captured in Amazon CloudTrail**.

From [Logging Amazon CloudWatch API Calls in AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/logging_cw_api_calls.html):

> The CloudWatch `GetMetricStatistics`, `ListMetrics`, and `PutMetricData` API actions are not supported.